# Permission denied error using Wkhtmltopdf on drupal 9 entityprint

Tags: 9

I downloaded the Wkhtmltopdf library using Homebrew and configured it on drupal 9 on the entityprint module on /admin/config/content/entityprint. It is in the /usr/local/bin directory, but when I try to print a PDF via drupal I get this error.

> Error generating document: Failed to generate PDF: sh: 1: /usr/local/bin/: Permission denied

I have given 777 permissions to that directory recursively.

Comment: It actually looks like you configured the module to execute ` /usr/local/bin/`, which is the name of the directory. Absent more info from you added to the question this is unanswerable unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had configured it wrong, i had put only the directory for the binary location, the correct configuration is attached in an image . thank you [image]